# ¿Cómo saber si una respuesta JSON está vacia en Xamarin Forms C#?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo un respuesta para saber si un **Json** tiene información dentro o no, en este caso lo que me interesa es saber si **Table1** contiene algo , y estoy tratando de hacer algo cómo esto.
Ya revisé y si obtengo respuesta y puedo parsear el json. Pero necesito saber si esta vacio.

```
switch (response.StatusCode) {
  //200
  case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    string xjson = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    try {
      //List<Table_Loc> loc_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table_Loc>>(xjson);
      lbl_res.Text = "Ordenes Pendientes";
      Root myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Root > (xjson);

      //var T1count = myobject.tablas.Table1.Count;

      if (myobject.tablas.Table1.Count == 0) {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = false;
      } else {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = true;
      }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
      await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
      return;
    }

    break;
}
```

pero cuando lo corro me dice que ....

> System.NullRefereceException:Object reference not set on an instance if an object ... en la linea donde estoy tratando de hacer el .Count

Esta mi respuesta JSON

```js
//Json
{
    "DatosEnvio": {},
    "DatosEnvioJson": {},
    "tablas": {
        "Table1": [
            {
                "aerolinea": "asw",
                "vuelo": "asd",
                "salida": "as",
                "sFecha": "2018-03-14T00:00:00",
                "sHora": "10:20:30",
                "regreso": "as",
                "rFecha": "2018-03-14T00:00:00",
                "rHora": "10:20:30",
                "motivo": "asdasdasdasdasd",
                "idOrden": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "bandera": "0",
    "mensaje": ""
}
```

Este es mi modelo

```
//Model ...

public class DatosEnvio
{
}

public class DatosEnvioJson
{
}

public class Table1
{
    public string aerolinea { get; set; }
    public string vuelo { get; set; }
    public string salida { get; set; }
    public DateTime sFecha { get; set; }
    public string sHora { get; set; }
    public string regreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime rFecha { get; set; }
    public string rHora { get; set; }
    public string motivo { get; set; }
    public int idOrden { get; set; }
}

public class Tablas
{
    public List<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public DatosEnvio DatosEnvio { get; set; }
    public DatosEnvioJson DatosEnvioJson { get; set; }
    public Tablas tablas { get; set; }
    public string bandera { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo 2 opciones:

Preguntas si las propiedades no son null en forma de cadea:

```
 if (myobject != null && myobject.tablas != null && myobject.tablas.Table1 != null &&  myobject.tablas.Table1.Count == 0) {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = false;
      } else {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = true;
      }
```

No se ve del todo elegante pero es la forma mas segura de asegurarse que todas las propiedades que llevan a `Table1` no sean `null` para evitar el error.

La otra manera es que si utilizas c# 6, puedes utilizar el [operador condicional de nulos `?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
 if (myobject?.tablas?.Table1?.Count == (int?)0) {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = false;
 }
  else {
        PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

Ya esta a tu decisión de cual utilizar.

---

Como extra tu codigo se puede simplificar en la siguiente manera:

```
PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = myobject?.tablas?.Table1?.Count == (int?)0;
```

Comment: Pues el error desapareció pero no hace lo que pido, trate tambien de almacenar el valor de Count ... con algo como esto
>  int check = myobject.tablas.Table1.Count; if (check > 0){ PasajeAereo.IsEnabled = true; }
Pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: Cual de las 2 formas utilizaste?

Comment: Ambas ... el código correo pero no para lo que necesito

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices 'no para lo que necesito'?

Comment: Necesito saber si Table1 tiene alguna info, para ello contamos lo que hay dentro si existe algo o el count es mayor a cero isenabled=true para uno de mis objetos ... eso no lo hace ...

Comment: En la condicion tienes tu preguntas si `Count` **es igual a 0 entonces dara `true`**, pero dices que debe de ser `true` cuando sea  **mayor** a `0`. Seguro que tu lógica esta bien?

Comment: Si así es, obviamente cambio un poco el código para que si fuese mayor a cero hiciera algo o no ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74879/discussion-between-einer-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).

Comment: Listo, tenía una clase por ahí mal y por eso no me contaba nada, muchas gracias :D